# Fail to catch event when call directive method from controller in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I try to call directive method from controller by using `$broadcast`.

But I catch event only if press on button twice.

See [Demo in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YHPZARjdsVMdQgomoa5s?p=preview)

Do I miss something?

Here is snippets of code:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <test-dir name="{{test}}"></test-dir>

    <select ng-model="broadcastTo" ng-options="x as x for x in ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']"></select>
    <button ng-click="broadcastToSelectedChild()">test</button>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {



  // a method that broadcasts to a selected child.
  $scope.broadcastToSelectedChild = function (){
    $scope.test = $scope.broadcastTo;

    console.log('call-' + $scope.test);

    $scope.$broadcast('call-' + $scope.test);
  };
});

app.directive('testDir', function (){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      'name': '@'
    },
    template: '<div>{{name}} called: {{called}}</div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

      scope.called = false;



      //set up the name to be used as the listened to event.
      var eventOn;
      scope.$watch('name', function(v) {
        console.log('listen ..','call-' + scope.name);
        if(eventOn){
          eventOn();
        }
        eventOn = scope.$on('call-' + scope.name, function (){
            alert(scope.name);
          });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Took example from: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165036/call-a-directive-controllers-method-from-parent-controller-in-angularjs)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because you bind your directive scope's `name` to your controller scope's `test`, but `ng-model` on the `<select>` binds to `broadcastTo`. When you select a value from the `<select>`, `test` is not updated and $watch inside your directive does not fire to attach the event handler.

Try:

```
<test-dir name="{{broadcastTo}}"></test-dir>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/TdRtNotOuI48LOMctnYN?p=preview)

In your code, you have to click twice because the first click updates `test` and causes $watch to fire to attach the event handler:

```
$scope.test = $scope.broadcastTo;
```

And the second click will be able to handle the event broadcast from your controller.

Comment: Right, it should work. The idea is that `broadcastToSelectedChild`  method called as modal callback. I posted simple version of code. I need somehow to make it works with `$scope.test = $scope.broadcastTo;
`

Comment: @fessy: I don't know what you're trying, but you need to ensure that when you select an item from the list, you need to update the `test` accordingly to fire the $watch. You could try `$scope.$watch("broadcastTo"` in your controller to update the `test`